# Want to know the behavior of html form in firefox?

Tags: javascript

I have an issue only in firefox:

I am generating query string using my own method with form like

```
<form name="mytestform" action="/submit.do">
   <input name="hiddenID" value="12345" type="hidden" > 
</form>
```

this page is called via ajax every time the value hiddenID changed every request.

When I am getting form data using **getFormData(mytestform)** it return the first accessed form value ( i.e all the time I am getting the value **hiddenId=12345** ) .

If I used **getFormData(document.mytestform)** it's working properly.

I am not sure the form objects are cached in firefox or not when i am using ajax .

Please explain me what's the logic behind it ?

Answer (score 1):

The browser has two versions of your page. The orignial what it looks like when it is loaded and the current version after all javascript is executed. If you view the source code of the page you get the original.

I guess the same thing happend here. By using document.mytestform you access the current version of the page.

Comment: yes,
I get the current form object when using document.mytestform.
In google chrome **document.mytestform** and **mytestform** returns the current form object. 
Is there any specific reasone , why it behave like this only in firefox ?

Comment: Because they told him so ;) No sorry, I can not explain why firefox behave this way.

Comment: do u have any reference link about this ?

Comment: Have a look at http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/611619-firefox-problem-accessing-form-value

Answer (score 0):

The default method of sending the form data is GET. This enables the response to be cached. If you do not want that behaviour use the POST method.

Comment: Hi,
Before sending request , When i am checked with firebug console
**getFormData(mytestform)** returns "hiddenId=12345" and **getFormData(document.mytestform)** returns newly changed value.

Answer (score 0):

The whole response will be cached unless you specify Expires: -1 as a header on the response or change the query string - even with AJAX.
A quick solution is to append new Date() as an extra parameter tot eh AJAX request
e.g.

```
$.GET("myURL/myForm.jsp?nocache="+new Date());
```

There are more elegant solutions, but this should hopefully be enough to prove it is caching that is your issue